# Query an existing object in creator function of association proxy using parent's instance attributes

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following models defined:

```
class Dictionary(Base):
    key = Column()
    value = Column()


class Attribute(Base):
    id = Column()
    name = Column()


class AttributeMap(Base):
    objtype_id = Column()
    attr_id = Column(foreign_keys='Attribute.id')

    rel_attr = relationship('Attribute')
    attr = association_proxy('rel_attr', 'name')


class AttributeValue(Base):
    object_id = Column(foreign_keys='Object.id')
    objtype_id = Column(foreign_keys='Object.objtype_id, AttributeMap.objtype_id')
    attr_id = Column(foreign_keys='AttributeMap.attr_id')
    uint_value = Column(foreign_keys='Dictionary.dict_key')

    rel_attr = relationship('AttributeMap')
    attr = association_proxy('rel_attr', 'attr')

    rel_value = relationship('Dictionary')
    value = association_proxy('rel_value', 'value')

class Object(Base):
    id = Column()
    objtype_id = Column(foreign_keys='Dictionary.dict_key')

    rel_objtype = relationship('Dictionary')
    objtype = association_proxy('rel_objtype', 'value')

    rel_attributes = relationship('AttributeValue', collection_class=attribute_mapped_collection('attr'), uselist=True)
    attributes = association_proxy('rel_attributes', 'value')
```

When to create an instance of *Object* class and add a new value to *attributes* collection during a single transactions. The usage should look like this:

```
obj = Object()
obj.rel_objtype = 'Dictionary value'
obj.attributes['Attribute name'] = 'another Dictionary value'
```

Assigning "Dictionary value" to "obj.rel_objtype" should result in query of existing Dictionary attribute:

```
obj.objtype = 'Dictionary value'
# => obj.rel_objtype = Dictionary.query().filter(Dictionary.value == 'Dictionary value').one()
```

Assigning "another Dictionary value" to "obj.attributes" should create a new instance of AttributeValue with "attr" = "Attribute name" and "value" = "another Dictionary value":

```
av = AttributeValue()
obj.rel_attributes['Attribute name'] = av

av.attr = 'Attribute name'
# => av.rel_attr = AttributeMap.query().filter(AttributeMap.attr == 'AttributeName').one()

av.value = 'another Dictionary value'
# => av.rel_value => Dictionary.query().filter(DictionaryValue.value == 'another Dictionary value').one()
```

The problem is that AttributeValue <-> AttributeMap relationship has two foreign keys: "attr_id" and "objtype_id". I have to use "objtype_id" for AttributeMap.query() to avoid duplicate entries in the result, but this value can be retrieved from the parent "Object" instance only.

How can I implement this?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to do this. It is called a _creator_ for a reason. Could you explain your use case because maybe there is a better approach for this (and we can easier understand what you try to achieve and come up with a solution)

Comment: I changed the question and provided a more complicated use case. There is no "creator" function anymore because I suspect this should be achieved by a different approach.

Comment: I'm not following every detail here but overall this looks like a vertical table approach presenting a dictionary facade.  We have an example of this technique in the dist at /examples/vertical, see http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/examples.html#vertical-attribute-mapping for the intro.